# How to write MySQL 5.7 query to find inconsistent data between two relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

We have a child-parents relationship in two tables:

**children table**:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `direct_parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `direct_parent_id_child_fk` (`direct_parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `direct_parent_id_child_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`direct_parent_id`) REFERENCES `child` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

| id | direct_parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 |
| 200 | 100 |
| 300 | 200 |

**parents table**:

```
CREATE TABLE `parents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `brand_id_parent_id_unx` (`child_id`,`parent_id`),
  KEY `parents_child_fk_idx` (`child_id`),
  KEY `parents_child_fk_2_idx` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parents_brand_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`) REFERENCES `child` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `brand_tree_brand_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `child` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

This table connects each child with:

1- itself

2- its direct parent

3- all parents of its parents

| id | child_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 | 200 |
| 3 | 200 | 100 |
| 4 | 300 | 300 |
| 5 | 300 | 200 |
| 6 | 300 | 100 |

Can we write SQL query (or more than one query) to find the children ids which don’t have the right data in parents table based on the children table?

For  example: the child id 300  have the direct parent 200, so all top parents will be parents for 300,  we should have these (child_id -> parent_id) records in the parents table:

300 -> 300

300 -> 200

300 -> 100

If one of them is not exist, or if id:300 has more records (for example 300 -> 400)  we want to return id:300 in our result

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm guessing you'll want to use `JOIN`

Comment: @barrycarter I can't find a suitable solution, I think it needs something like recursion or for loops but I'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

Querying all the records in the `parents` table that have a `parent_id` higher than the `direct_parent_id` but it's not the `child_id` itself

```
SELECT p.child_id, p.parent_id FROM parents p, children c
where p.child_id = c.id
and p.parent_id > c.direct_parent_id
and p.parent_id != p.child_id
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what Im looking for, please re-read the question, thanks.

Comment: @light can you elaborate on your question then? actual example of input and output expected? what exactly didn't worked in my query? here's a dbfiddle that shows my query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=79b133085f5dde1aefb356788c44817b

Comment: We need to retrieve 600 and 700 in this case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=965e9897f6ba8d6d7dd7af427114e6a6